# Why is $_POST Empty in Profile Edit Admin?

Tags: posts, admin, array, profiles

This is a very odd problem - post data seems to be empty in the profile editing page of admin.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/3ejg8P99

What causes this? Is there some "safety" step I've missed or something?

Comment: Apparently this page comes after a redirect, so no wonder the $_POST show's empty. Had to catch the posted variables using these actions: 

    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'symbiostock_update_social_credentials' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'symbiostock_update_social_credentials' );

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment.